# Decoding Binary Data in Python

Tags: python

I am attempting to decode some binary from an old document I have got hold of and I'm struggling.

This is what I have:

```
FBE80YlsYgAIhjELHyhxUyQsNyQrawAMOgAQEAAQEAAIDwAUrgARCQAQHAATiAAY1QcwGQ
AMMCbJCAARIgAMc4qUV4iRIgAUuAARtAAUV4iRUgAMPAAJKQ9sRoiRtAAUOCbBSJf0OwAJ
jYIJjYIChhCq+v1bS0tHR0Y=
```

This code I then decode via Base64 to get this binary

```
0001010000010001001111001101000110001001011011000110001000000000000010
0010000110001100010000101100011111001010000111000101010011001001000010
1100001101110010010000101011011010110000000000001100001110100000000000
0100000001000000000000000100000001000000000000000010000000111100000000
0001010010101110000000000001000100001001000000000001000000011100000000
0000010011100010000000000000011000110101010000011100110000000110010000
0000000011000011000000100110110010010000100000000000000100010010001000
0000000000110001110011100010101001010001010111100010001001000100100010
0000000000010100101110000000000000010001101101000000000000010100010101
1110001000100100010101001000000000000011000011110000000000000010010010
1001000011110110110001000110100010001001000110110100000000000001010000
1110000010011011000001010010001001011111110100001110110000000000001001
1000110110000010000010011000110110000010000000101000011000010000101010
101111101011111101010110110100101101001011010001110100011101000110
```

Then the only information I have is the following:

```
(length = 2, value = 2) (length = 1, value = 0)
00010 10 00001 0
```

And somehow the resulting and this binary `00100 1111` the document states equals `15` I have no idea how it came to this.

I did this in python but kind of got lost?

```
def getDivision(code):
    if not code:
        return "Unknown division code"
    base64data = base64.b64decode(code)
    binaryData = ""
    for x in base64data:
        a = bin(x)[2:]
        while len(a) < 8:
            a = "0" + a
        binaryData = binaryData + a
    header = int(binaryData[12:17], 2)
    code = binaryData[17:17 + header]

    print(code)
```

Help explaining how this come about would be fantastic.

Comment: I’m confused—is this your code and you’re wanting to know how to make it work a particular way, or is it someone else’s code you want to interpret?

Comment: @bob The python code at the bottom was my attempt to interpret it. Basically the "division" = 15 is the result someone seemed to get in the document, I'm struggling to get that same result with whats been provided. So I want to understand how I'm supposed to be interpretting the initial "document" stuff to best adjust me python code at the bottom.

Comment: The "15" comes from a third iteration of the pattern you quoted: a 5-bit length, followed by that many bits of value.  I have no idea why this value would be described as a "division", and the pattern clearly does not continue for the entire file as it breaks down after at most one further iteration.  What is this data supposed to BE, anyway?

Comment: It is a "deck" for a game, the full data value contains many things - like what that deck comprises of in terms of units, number of cards, veterancy etc. However I'm only interested in the bit value for the division because that returned value will give me the division identifier. The ultimate goal is how in python can I get the "15" into a variable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the pattern continued on, with a 5-bit length followed by that length of a bit string, you'd get this before it breaks down:

```
at 0, length 2 value 2
at 7, length 1 value 0
at 13, length 4 value 15
at 22, length 6 value 35
at 33, length 2 value 1
at 40, length 13 value 4488
at 58, length 0 value 0
at 63, length 0 value 0
at 68, length 17 value 6340
at 90, length 5 value 17
at 100, length 30 value 339257746
at 135, length 2 value 3
at 142, length 1 value 1
at 148, length 14 value 4629
at 167, length 22 value 2883632
```

Here's the code that produced that:

```
import base64
import struct

s = b"""\
FBE80YlsYgAIhjELHyhxUyQsNyQrawAMOgAQEAAQEAAIDwAUrgARCQAQHAATiAAY1QcwGQ
AMMCbJCAARIgAMc4qUV4iRIgAUuAARtAAUV4iRUgAMPAAJKQ9sRoiRtAAUOCbBSJf0OwAJ
jYIJjYIChhCq+v1bS0tHR0Y="""

data = base64.b64decode(s)
print(' '.join(hex(i) for i in data[0:8]))

def getbits(data,p,n):
    byte = p//8
    val = struct.unpack('>I',data[byte:byte+4])[0]
    val >>= (32-(p&7)-n)
    val &= (1 << n) - 1
    return val

pos = 0
while True:
    length = getbits(data,pos,5)
    val = getbits(data,pos+5,length)
    print(f"at {pos}, length {length} value {val}")
    pos += 5 + length
```

All I do here is track the current bit position within the bit string, using `pos`.   The main loop asks for 5 bits to get the length, then asks for that many bits as the value.

In the function that gets the bits, I divide the position by 8 to get the byte number where the string starts.  Since a field might span several bytes, I took the easy way out and convert the 4 bytes starting at that byte number to a 32-bit integer.  (Thats what `struct.unpack` is doing.)  I have to use ">I" to tell `struct` to treat the bytes as big-endian so that the first byte becomes the most significant byte.

OK, so now I have all the bits we want all together in a single integer value, but in the middle of the integer.  We need to shift the field down to bit 0.  For the very first case, where we want 5 bits starting at position 0, we need to shift right by 27 bits to get our field to the bottom.  That's 32-5.  But, if the field we want is not aligned at the very top we have to account for that offset as well.  That results in:

```
    val >>= 32 - (p&7) - n
```

Now, the field we want is at the bottom of the integer.  We just need to get rid of whatever extra bits there might have been beyond the 5 bits we wanted.  The way you get an N-bit binary mask is to take 1, shift left by N, then subtract 1:

```
    val &= (1 << n) - 1
```

Here's an example.  Let's start with your decoded binary, and say we've already pull the first two fields, so we're positioned at bit 13:

```
0001010000010001001111001101000110001001
             ^----
```

Let me divide that into bytes:

```
14 11 3C D1 89
00010100 00010001 00111100 11010001 10001001
              ^-- --
```

So, for position 13, that means we are in byte 1, bit number 5 (counting from the top, which is unusual).  I use struct.unpack to produce val, which will be 0x113CD189.  We are pulling 5 bits, so our shift will be 32 - 5 - 5, or 22.  Shifting that value right by 22 bits produces:

```
0x44
00000000 00000000 00000000 01000100
```

Now we create the mask, which is (1 << 5) - 1, and "and" it with the shifted value:

```
(1 << 5)    is    00000000 00100000
(1 << 5) -1 is    00000000 00011111
------------------------------------
00000000 00000000 00000000 00000100
```

The result is 4, so we're going to grab the next 4 bytes as the value.

Comment: so how would I specific get the "15"? I'm trying to understand it as a whole really.

Comment: As you can see, 15 is the value of the third record.  What leads you to think you need the third field, besides that someone else came up with that number?

Comment: The 3rd field I know from document is the field that describes the division - the division is then an identifier (as a base 2 int I belive) I can match to another document to obtain a name and relationshipid.

Comment: I've tried some additional deck codes using your above code and it appears that the 3rd iteration returns the value that I need each time, even for the different codes/decks. Is there any chance you can break down the code for my understanding? I'm not a fan of just having the code do the work, I like to understand how so for my own education. I'm a Data Engineer by trade, programming is a "hobby" as it were.

Comment: I'll add comments.